# Access Raspberry Pi behind a NAT firewall through Internet

Tags: raspberry-pi, routers

I have been developing projects with Raspberry Pi 4. For the current project I am running a NextCloudPi server on it. I am able to access the server using my Internal IP. I want to access it using a public domain name or in other words through open Internet. My ISP does not allow port forwarding and static IP.

I tried Zerotier, which creates a VPN and I can access the CloudServer through the static IP assigned under VPN but the transfer speeds are really slow. Another issue is that I need to install it on all the devices through which I am going to access the CloudServer and ofcourse on the RPi4 itself.

Is there any other option that you guys have to access RPi4 (basically IoT devices) through Internet?
Any suggestion would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Dyndns + port forwarding? Probably more appropriate on superuser rather than here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have finally resolved the issue. I have used `ngork` to create virtual tunnel. I tried to use `ngork` earlier but was unable as I was running the service on *port 80*. When I ran the `nrogk` http service on *port 443*, I was able to access the NextCloud server using the domain name shown on the ssh terminal. NextCloud uses *port 80 for http* and *443 for https*. I am really not sure why I was not able to access the NextCloud on *port 80*. This may help if someone is stuck in the similar problem. The problem with `ngork` is, once the raspberry pi is restarted you will have to restart the `ngork` service as well and of course the domain address will also be changed. Though my use case don't have any problem with it.